# Floating of Divs not exact. How to arrange them the right way?

Tags: jquery, html, css

As you can see in the screenshot: [image]

the order is not that perfect. 
I like to arrange the articles without any gaps. 
Means like this:

[image]

Any ideas how i can manage that via CSS/CSS3 or javascript? Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you share the code your using it would help ...

Comment: its private cause to not launched yet. sorry. But "ashley" posted the answer i was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use CSS, but the problem is, the property only supports >IE10. Which then you could fallback to jQuery Masonry

http://jsfiddle.net/4gXCs/

```
.col {
   -moz-column-count:2; 
   -webkit-column-count:2; 
   column-count:10px;
   -moz-column-gap:10px;
   -webkit-column-gap:10px; 
   column-gap:2;
}
```

Comment: damn awesome!!! this is exactly how i liked it to be done! THANKS!!! even if its just >IE10.

Answer (score 7):

I am afraid this is how floats work in CSS. You might want to try using [**jQuery Masonry**](http://masonry.desandro.com/) for what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to use `masonry plugin`

**http://masonry.desandro.com/**

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean something like this?

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4gXCs/2/)**

Done using Two vertical div's

```
<div class="one">
    <div class="leftTop"></div>
    <div class="leftBot"></div>
</div>
<div class="two">
    <div class="rightTop"></div>
    <div class="rightBot"></div>
</div>
```